# Issue with vcvars32.bat when trying to use cl Visual Studio command for command line build via the system() function in a c++ program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, environment-variables, command-prompt, cl

I'm trying to compile a generated cpp file from within another c++ program.

To begin (to see if the cl command works) I'm trying to use the Visual Studio command line build from the c++ program like this:

> command("cl");

Since the c++ command prompt isn't a native tools command prompt I first call:

> command("C:"/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual \ Studio/2019/Community/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars32.bat"");

Which seems to execute fine, with the expected output. However when I do the cl call after I get:

> 'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

which is the same expected error as if I didn't call the vcvars32.bat.

If I do exactly the same process from a regular command prompt everything works, however not from the c++ program cmd from my Visual Studio 2019 C++ 17 project.

I'm not super surprised that it isn't working, I assume that there is something different with the environment of the C++ project which despite the successful vcvars32.bat call won't set up the environment variables in a required way.

Does anyone know exactly what this could depend on and (if possible) how to fix it? Or if you have any other idea of how I can compile a c++ project from another c++ program?

Comment: What is `command()`? I assume each `command` starts new shell instance, so each run you get the initial environment.

Comment: Try `C:"/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual \ Studio/2019/Community/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars32.bat" & cl ...`

Comment: Thank you that seems to have worked! I assumed the command was done in the same shell since the result was written in the same VS project command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, as S.M pointed out, system() opens a new shell between each call.
I resolved it using the operator & and run the vcvars32.bat and the cl command in the same system call as proposed by Paul Sanders.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, `cl` isn't in your path. You need to add [it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/setting-the-path-and-environment-variables-for-command-line-builds?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019). The recommended way to do this is to launch a developer command prompt. You could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/cl-environment-variables?view=vs-2019) about how to set CL environment variables.

Also, you need to set up toolsets. If you have a plain Command Prompt window open, you can run the batch file `vcvarsall.bat` with the appropriate argument to set up the environment variables.

1. At the command prompt, change to the Visual C++ installation
   directory. (The location depends on the system and the Visual Studio
   installation, but a typical location is C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio version\VC.) For example, enter:

   cd "\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC"
2. To configure this Command Prompt window for 32-bit x86 command-line builds, at the command prompt, enter:

   vcvarsall x86

The possible arguments are the following:

```
x86 (x86 32-bit native)
x86_amd64 (x64 on x86 cross)
x86_arm (ARM on x86 cross)
amd64 (x64 64-bit native)
amd64_x86 (x86 on x64 cross)
amd64_arm (ARM on x64 cross)
```

If the `ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools Folder` occurs when you run `vcvar32`, you could check whether there is `c:\windows\system32` in the environment variable PATH. If not, you could add it. Because `vcvar32` will call a command called `reg` when it is running. And this `reg` command needs `c:\windows\system32`.

Comment: Thank you, however, this looks like an answer for how to do it manually. What I tried to do was to use my VS project command prompt via c++ code using the c++ system() function. The issue was that system() opens a new shell between each call.